# How do I stop GitHub Conduit?

Tags: launchd, git

How do I stop GitHub Conduit and keep GitHub.app from reinstalling the job in launchd?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two steps to stopping GitHub Conduit: telling GitHub.app to not re-install the job with launchd and telling launchd to not run it anymore.

Disable Conduit installation:

`defaults write com.github.GitHub GHShouldDisableConduit -bool yes`

Remove launchd job:

`launchctl remove com.github.GitHub.Conduit`

Comment: this may also be useful, I haven't been able to totally remove atom (which I would like) but I've been able to get the log to stop printing with:
`launchctl stop com.github.GitHub.ShipIt`

Answer (score 0):

[The Secrets Pref Pane for Mac](http://secrets.blacktree.com) has the ability to turn this off for you. It's an opensource tool for managing hidden things on your Mac. You can also turn it off at the Terminal with:

```
defaults write com.github.GitHub GHShouldDisableConduit -boolean yes
```

Comment: Yes, I think I may have added it to their database. 

Comment: Just to let new readers know, Secrets is a now dead project and the website that drives the tool is gone.